# Plot ggplots stored in list over several pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know similar questions have been already asked so sorry if this is a redundant question! However, I can't seem to find a solution that arranges several ggplots from a list onto 1 page over several pages.

I have a list of approximately 100 ggplots - I want to plot every 4 ggplots on 1 page, and iterate through the list until all the ggplots have been plotted. I then want to export the approximately 25 pages to a single pdf file.

So far, I've tried:

```
pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE, width = 11, height = 8.5)
for (i in 0:24) {
    ggarrange(list[[4i+1]], list[[4i+2]], list[[4i+3]], list[[4i+4]], 
    nrow = 2, ncol = 2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = 'bottom'
}
dev.off()
```

However, I'm getting the error that the subscript is out of bounds. I've tried narrowing the range in the for loop to try to overcome this error but it's returning the same error. I also know we can use marrangeGrob(), but I can't seem to add a common legend to the file.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: indexing in `R` starts from 1 i.e. `for(i in 1:25)`.  Did you meant `4 * i + 1`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that!! That was causing my initial error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide some small list of plots to test on.

I have tried to recreate your scenario, and have found that it wasn't working unless I explicitly `print` the `ggarrange` object.

```
plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

plot_list <- list(plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot, plot)

pdf("test.pdf", 11, 8.5)
for(i in 0:3){
  print(ggarrange(plot_list[[2*i + 1]], plot_list[[2*i + 1]], nrow = 2, ncol = 1))
}

dev.off()
```

This worked for me. Noting akrun's comment that you forgot your `*` symbol.

Comment: Thank you both for your response!! The * symbol was the cause of my previous grief and the print() resolved any other issues I had!